# Can't Build Gatsby With UseAxios, It Raise Error : UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80

Tags: reactjs, axios, gatsby

This is my 404.tsx page component, Hi, I'm having a problem when building gatsby withgatsby build always getting this error, FYI I use axios-hooks , how to solve this please?, but it works fine while development

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Box, Typography, makeStyles, Grid, useMediaQuery, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import { Link } from 'gatsby';
import useAxios from 'axios-hooks';


export default function NotFound404() {
    const [{ data: latestArticles = {}, loading: loadingLatestArticles }] = useAxios({
        baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT,
        url: 'latest-articles',
    });

return (
    <Box>
        
    </Box>
);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping it inside a this condition:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Box, Typography, makeStyles, Grid, useMediaQuery, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import { Link } from 'gatsby';
import useAxios from 'axios-hooks';


export default function NotFound404() {
    if(typeof window !=="undefined"){
    const [{ data: latestArticles = {}, loading: loadingLatestArticles }] = useAxios({
        baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT,
        url: 'latest-articles',
    });
    }
return (
    <Box>
        
    </Box>
);
```

*Note: define as empty your variables outside the condition and override it inside it if needed.*

> but it works fine while development

Usually when something works in `gatsby develop` but not in `gatsby build` if because of the [availability of global objects, such as `window` or `document`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/). You need to keep in mind that `gatsby develop` occurs in the browser while `gatsby build` occurs in the Node server (where there are no global objects because they are not defined yet), so the code will behave differently in both environments. This condition:

```
if(typeof window !=="undefined")
```

Will ensure that the code is rendered in the browser, avoiding being triggered in the server.